# Having my div disappearing before continue process

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have the following jQuery script:

```
function fctSaveSuccess(data) {
    fctHideLoadingDlg();
    alert('continue...');
    ...
}

function fctHideLoadingDlg(disableBtn) {
    $("#loading").fadeTo(5000, 0.5, function () {
        $("#loading").dialog('destroy').remove();
    });
}
```

What I would like to achieve is having my loading div (a kind of popup for waiting) to disappear slowly. But it doesn't work because when fctHideLoadingDlg is called the code below it continue to be executed even if I have set a fading of 5000...

Any idea how can I prevent this?

Thanks.

Comment: Note: Don't call `$('#loading')` twice unnecessarily, that is very inefficient. That means querying the DOM two times. Use `$(this)` or cache the result in a variable and use that.

Comment: It would be a good idea to set up a jsFiddle that demonstrates your problem. What is the starting opacity of the div? Is it possible that it is already `0.5` when you start the animation? I don't see any possible problem in the *currently shown* code.

Comment: I create a jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/uDNtY/2/ when clicking on the link, you'll see the alert message even if the fadeOut is not finished. That's my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is quite normal. The execution of `fctSaveSuccess` will not be blocked, because `fctHideLoadingDlg` will return right after calling `fadeTo`. `fadeTo` is passed a callback that will run when it completes, but that does not block.

You could take the same callback route in your code. Functions are objects in Javascript, so they can also be easily passed around as parameters:

```
function fctSaveSuccess(data) { 
    var afterHide = function () {
        alert('continue...'); 
        /* rest of your code */
    };
    fctHideLoadingDlg(afterHide); 
} 

function fctHideLoadingDlg(callback, disableBtn) { 
    $("#loading").fadeOut(5000, function () { 
        callback();
        $("#loading").dialog('destroy').remove(); 
    }); 
}
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uDNtY/3/)